# getting stuck at c program how do I stop scanf in the middle of process

Tags: c, algorithm, scanf

I am writing a small program that takes input of country name which consist of 3 letters and the amount of medals the country has won in an Olympics and the program will keep asking for input unless the word "end" is entered. I wrote a while loop to do this however I can't seem to stop

```
//Program calculate the winner of olympics based on metal input
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (void)
{
    int maxMedals=0, tempGold=0, tempSilver=0, tempBronze=0,tempSum;
    char country[3];
    char winner[3];
    printf("\no o o    O L Y M P I C    o o o");
    printf("\n o o      S C O R E S      o o\n");
    printf("Enter country code, # gold, # silver, # bronze\n");
    while ((strcmp(country,"end"))!=0)
    {
        printf("==>");
        scanf("%s %d %d %d",&country, &tempGold, &tempSilver, &tempBronze);
        tempSum=tempGold+tempSilver+tempBronze;
        if (maxMedals<tempSum)
        {
            maxMedals = tempSum;
            strcpy(winner, country);
            // printf("\n %s", winner);
        }
        else
        {
            maxMedals=maxMedals;
        }
    }
    printf("\nwe reached here\n");
    printf("\nWinner is %s with %d medals\n", country, maxMedals);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the case of this program it won't stop even when I type in end because that it would still ask for 3 extra integer input for the score is there anyway to "cut short" of the scanf when it detects the word "end" been entered

Comment: You have to use separate `scanfs` rather use `fgets` to get country.

Comment: @user2948725 just remove `&` before `country` then every thing ok.

Comment: yeah I will look into fgets too because I am pretty new to C thanks though I will definitely look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%s",&country);
if (strcmp(country,"end") == 0)
    break;
scanf("%d %d %d", &tempGold, &tempSilver, &tempBronze);
```

Hope this change works. First you get input for country, if it is not `end` then it proceeds for getting other options. Even if four params are entered in a line, this will work.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&country);` not but `scanf("%s",country);`

Comment: No need to use `&` for `country` in `scanf()`.

Comment: do you mean that I have to split the scanf into two scanfs that stack over each other and if let's say one of them detects the "end" then I cut the program short?

Comment: Just copy pasted from the question:) But i think `country, &country, &country[0]` are all pointing to same address.

Comment: @user2948725 yes, the `scanf` has to be split into two, there are other ways ofcourse, but this one is just with `scanf`

Comment: no unfortunately removing & did nothing same thing happend it just expects 3 more inputs after the end I guess I have to split it into 2 scanfs thanks though guys I'll try fix this by splitting into 2 scanfs appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `country` is only 3 characters long. In C, `scanf` writes a hex 0 character to indicate the end of the string, and `strcmp` compares strings all the way up to the hex 0 (at least until the strings differ), so you need at least 4 characters for `"end"`.

By only have space for 3 and writing 3 + the hex 0, you're overflowing into unknown memory, causing [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). By printing out `country` on my machine, it prints `"endend"`, meaning `winner` appears to be directly after `country` in memory, so it prints both of those, since `printf` also continues until it finds a hex 0, but, since this is undefined behaviour, this behaviour isn't guaranteed and may be different on a different compiler.

Try making it 4 characters:

```
char country[4];
```

---

Also, your loop isn't correct - you still process `"end"` as you only check for that after processing it.

Two ways of dealing with this problem:

- Put an if-statement right after the `scanf` to check for "end" which would `break`.
- Put a `scanf` *before* the while-loop, and *at the end* of the while loop (so 2 identical `scanf`'s).

Comment: but wouldn't the value in the strings stay there after I scanned in the values? so next time when it run the while loop it would detect the end and stop it? just wondering

Comment: When reading "end", you'll go scan, process, stop. If you don't mind processing "end", you don't need to change your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can break your `scanf` as below.. So when you enter "`end`" you will be out of `while`.

```
scanf("%s",country);
if(strcmp(country,"end")==0) 
   break;

scanf("%d %d %d",&tempGold, &tempSilver, &tempBronze);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `country` with "end" before you input, when you input `end 1 1 1`, your program would stop. But your code may cause a buffer overflow since the `country` and `winner` are declared as `char country[3];` `char winner[3];`, string in C need a extra `\0` as terminal character in the end. If you need to input only an "end" to terminate the program, just split the `scanf` as you say.

Comment: arh yes I noticed that too yeah this is under the assumption that only the offical 3 letter abbreviate of the country would be entered yeah I'll have to fix the program by split the scanf it seems

Comment: @user2948725 Even only 3 letters, you need at least 4 chars.